# How much does a linear lightyear of space expand in a year?

Tags: expansion

Now that we know that the universe is expanding, how much does a linear lightyear of space expand currently in a year?

Answer (score 8):

A recent estimation of the [Hubble constant is 71.9 (km/s)/Mpc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble%27s_law).

This means there is an expansion of

$$\left(71.9\ \mathrm{\frac{km}{s\ Mpc}}\right)\left(\mathrm{\frac{60\ s}{min}}\right)\left(\mathrm{\frac{60\ min}{hr}}\right)\left(\mathrm{\frac{24\ hr}{day}}\right)\left(\mathrm{\frac{365\ day}{yr}}\right) = 2,267,438,400\ \mathrm{\frac{km}{yr\ Mpc}}$$

To apply this expansion over a light year:

$$
\frac{2,267,438,400\ \mathrm{(km/yr)/Mpc}}{3,261,564\ \mathrm{lyr/Mpc}} = \boxed{695.2\ \mathrm{\frac{km/yr}{lyr}}}
$$

which is about $7.3483\times10^{-11}\ \%$ per year or $432\ \mathrm{miles/year}$.

A linear light year of space expands by 695.2 km/yr with a given Hubble constant of 71.9 (km/s)/Mpc.

Edit:
A better measurement released on 2018-02-22 using parallax found the Hubble constant to be [73.45 ± 1.66 (km/s)/Mpc.](http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hvi/uploads/science_paper/file_attachment/308/finalpass5.pdf)